After executing firebase deploy --only hosting and I click on the URL I am directed to a weird page
I am deploying a flutter web app firebase hosting by using the firebase deploy --only hosting command.
The command finishes without any errors and gives me a URL.
When I click on the URL I see a screen with a button to go to documentation instead of to my app. The URL in index.html is not the URL I was expecting. WHY?
Here is the screenshot of the page:

Why am I not seeing my app?
Here is my firebase.json:
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

My directory structure is as follows:
main project folder/build/web
I thought when I deployed my app I would be able to see it in a browser. What am I missing?

Include your Firebase config, e.g., firebase.json, not your index.html, and include your directory structure where these files exist.

Thank you for your response. I added the information you asked for.

Are you running flutter build web before you run firebase deploy? Does build/web/index.html exist before you run firebase deploy?

Yes, it already existed.
